# Finitely generated $k$-algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry

When I look the definition of affine domain, the google says finitely generated as an algebra over a field. Do we need the generators are transcendental over a field?

Comment: Possible not all the generators but by Noether normalization lemma, the number of transcendental generators (transcendence degree of the field of rational function of our affine variety) is equal to the dimension of the affine variety.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, for example, a finite extension is a finitely generated algebra.

In general, as pointed out by Ehsan in the comments, a finitely generated algebra **contains**, and is finite (as module) over, a polynomial ring $k[X_1, \dots, X_n]$ with $n\ge 0$.

Comment: And as your first sentence indicates, it is possible that $n = 0$.  (For the OP: the case $n = 0$ corresponds geometrically to a $0$-dimensional affine algebraic set, i.e. a finite set of points.)

Comment: @MichaelJoyce: yes, thanks.